# Group different groups as the same and count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT owner,
         typeOwner,
         type,
         count(*) AS count
    FROM myTable 
GROUP BY typeOwner 
ORDER BY count DESC 
   LIMIT 0, 30
```

Now , the `typeOwner values = '<test>a</test>'` but , some times the `typeOwner` field will have some string else like `'<test>b</test>`, how can i let this query count the `<test>b</test>` as a group of `'<test>a</test>`.

I want to make an exception for this, I mean `typeOwner <test>a</test>` AND `typeOwner <test>b</test>` should be counted as one row that have two count.

here's a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70053/1 , take look

actually these are should be grouped by `<type></type><aId></aId>`

Comment: Do you always want to ignore the single quote, like `'<test>i'm</test>'` would turn to `<test>im<test>`... or, would that never even happen, is `typeOwner` always simply `a,b,c,etc...`

Comment: what is it to do with the question @Tom ? i dont get it, is there a way to do the above query with the exception i explained ?

Comment: Well, you could simply use `REPLACE` to replace all instances of an apostrophe if you don't want them at all.  If they may happen in places where you don't want to lose them, that wouldn't be a good option.

Comment: i need the data inside of each row of the table that matches with the query, but some of values have little differences , the differences are the options that i'm using outside of sql. so , some of options are different.@Tom

Comment: Oh, oops, I didn't get the question.  The way the formatting was done in the question, some of the code has an apostrophe and some didn't, making me believe that was part of the problem.

Comment: Your question maybe isn't as much about grouping as it is about how to pattern match your different values. And for that we need more info about the data.

Comment: @KarlKieninger yes you are right ! i edited my question and added an sqlfiddle , please take look , its show everything

Comment: So in the fiddle you would want to basically ignore the <xtype> stuff and gorup on what looks like the first to elements? So you would have only two tows in the result? Is that the a consistent pattern across the data?

Comment: Exactly ! i want to grouping by `<type>` and `<aId>` and as you say ignoring `<xType>`  @KarlKieninger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "actually these are should be grouped by "

You can GROUP BY something relatively ugly like:

```
GROUP BY LEFT(typeOwner, position('<xType>' in typeOwner) -1)
```

But you are probably better off preprocessing the data in some fashion. I'm not sure how MySQL handles xml, but in SQL server I might extract the XML values into first class relation fields if I needed to do this sort of processing with any frequency.

[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70053/9/0)

Comment: Dude , the sql you wrote , works like charm ! is it gonna be a problem ? i mean , as you say " relatively ugly " xD, the database gonna be have alots of data , like Thousands of rows. is it will work just fine or its gonna be problem later ? it seems cool.

Comment: No particular problem. By "relatively ugly" I convey a general distaste for this sort of frequent/Representative string manipulation in SQL. So I would consider extract the xml elements into separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sqlfiddle, this works

```
SELECT 
left(typeOwner, instr(typeOwner, '<xType>')-1) as typeOwner,
owner,type, count(*) as count 
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY left(typeOwner, instr(typeOwner, '<xType>')-1)  
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: then I am not clear on what you want. is it just <test>a</test> and <test>b</test> that you want to group together? what are the other values in the column you want to group together?

Comment: Take into consideration, i have `typeOwner` with value of `<test>a</test><test2>x</test2>`
 another row `typeOwner` with value of `<test>a</test><test2>y</test2>` , i want these both as one row ( it will count two )

Comment: @user2077916 - provide your exact rules for what should be grouped and what shouldn't.

Comment: @user2077916 - that is helpful, but I still need to understand which ones should be grouped and which ones shouldn't.

Comment: its grouping by `<type>a</type><aId>14</aId><xType>y</x>` as you see , we have 3 of that , the `<type>a</type><aId>14</aId><xType>s</x>` should be grouped with the first one ( `<type>a</tyle><aId>14</aId>` )

Comment: so, it is the value inside of <aId> that you want to group on? is that your grouping rule?

Comment: Type and aId , these two  ( <type>a</type><aId>14</aId> )